# Getting client-side HTML from Javascript generated page using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I am trying to write some code which captures limited information from webpages by using the following code in Google Apps Script:

```
var url = "myurlhere.com";
var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
const RegexExp = /(?<=<span class=\"text-match\">).*?(?=<\/span>)/gi;
var result = str1.match(RegexExp);
```

And this works BEAUTIFULLY. The problem comes when the `url` page source is a client-side Javascript creation. I am crawling all over the internet, and basically everywhere I have looked, I get the same answer... "you need a headless browser", "use Node.js or Phantom.js".

This is irrelevant to me. I am not the owner of the HTML file, so I am either missing something or Node.js does not work here, and Phantom.js will not work because this is not my local machine.

My current thoughts toward a solution... create a pop-up using Apps Script (load the entire webpage, not just the Javascript source), and find a way to grab the generated HTML (the stuff you see when you "inspect" a page), but this is where I get stuck. I'm looking for an expert who may know best how to interface with a chrome tab and grab this information with Google Apps Script.

Current attempt progress:

```
function openURLdata() {
  var js = " \
    <script> \
      window.open('myurlhere.com', 'URLdata', 'width=800, height=600'); \
      google.script.host.close(); \
    </script> \
  ";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);

  Logger.log(html.getContent());
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); // If you use this on Spreadsheet

}
```

Does anyone know if this is a step in the right direction? Does Google's server-side communications mean that I won't ever get a plain text interpretation of the HTML page that I need my data from? I have to get this task done in Google Sheets, and the target site does not have an API I can use.

Comment: You need to run the JavaScript to get the output. You can try something like [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).

Comment: I just tried this in Google Apps Script and get the error "ReferenceError: require is not defined". I'm not sure I can run pure Javascript like this on Google Apps. My exact attempt is `function mintAttempt() {
  
  url = "https://www.mintscan.io/osmosis/validators/osmovaloper1hjct6q7npsspsg3dgvzk3sdf89spmlpf6t4agt"
  
  const jsdom = require("jsdom");
  const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  const dom = new JSDOM(str, {
        runScripts: "dangerously",
        resources: "usable"
    });

}`

Comment: See https://jeffy.info/2021/07/12/npm-from-apps-script.html?

Comment: `The latest versions of jsdom require Node.js v12 or newer` - it's not going to work in a browser.

Comment: So even if I package it up as shown in jeffy.info/2021/07/12/npm-from-apps-script.html, using a deprecated version of jsdom, I can't get this done?